# Print out a set of integers from args with the output: The numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Tags: java, arrays, variables, integer, args

How do i print out a set of integers in an args array. **I intend to have an output of: The numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5**

```
System.out.println("The numbers are ");
    for(int i=0; i< args.length;i++)
    System.out.print(args[i] + " ";
```

The compiler gives me an error of *"i cannot be resolved to a variable"* When i resolve it with *"int b = 0;"* it gives me a single integer, rather than the integers in args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Java 5 you can also skip `i` entirely:

```
for( String arg : args )
   System.out.print(arg + " ");
```

Additionally, I'd like to advocate using curly braces even for one-statement blocks.
It's easier to read and less likely to change the behavior by adding a statement (like some log statement).

Example, a naive `pow()` method (checks skipped for simplicity):

Orignal code:

```
int pow(int base, int power) { //assume power to be > 1
 int result = base;

 for( int i = 1; i <= power; i++ ) 
   result *= base;

 return result;
}
```

Now I'd like to log the result in each step:

```
int pow(int base, int power) { //assume power to be > 1
  int result = base;

  for( int i = 1; i <= power; i++ ) 
    System.out.println( base + " pow( " + i + ") = " + result );
    result *= base;

  return result;
}
```

Suddenly, I get a wrong result for `power > 2`, since now `result *= base;` is only executed once (it is now outside the loop).

Answer (score 3):

If that is your actual code, you are missing an ending parenthesis in the last line before the semi-colon.

This works for me:

```
public class tester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("The numbers are ");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Output (when 1 2 3 4 5 are specified on the cmd line):

```
The numbers are 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgot parenthesis?

```
System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your `println` method with a `);`.

Your problem:

```
System.out.print(args[i] + " ";
```

Your solution:

```
System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
```